# LM358 Headphone Amplifier Oscillations

Tags: amplifier, oscillation, distortion, push-pull

I'm trying to build a very simple headphone amplifier for my bass guitar. The bass has a built-in amplifier, meaning that unity-gain is sufficient for my amplifier, I essentially only need a voltage buffer.

To this end, I've used an LM358 (because that's what I had laying around) and a BC547 / BC557 push-pull output stage. Supply voltage is 9V which is overkill, since my signal is no more than 2 Vpp.

The problem is, that the output signal that I'm hearing is quite distorted. I can hear the clean signal but there are some undesired high-frequency components as well. Using an oscilloscope I was able to verify that the distortion is not due to clipping. However, I don't have a function generator, so I can't test if the culprit is cross-over distortion (shouldn't be though, since I've added biasing) or if there's some parasitic oscillation going on.

Anybody see a problem with the circuit right away?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzwROb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks

Edit: I've been able to get a hold of a function generator. Here's a new scope screen capture (10kHz sinusoidal input) which seems to show some funny business around the zero-crossing. Blue = input, purple = output

[image: Scope capture for 10kHz sinusoidal input]

Comment: There's a chance that it's oscillating due to phase shift between the transistors adn the output.  There's also the fact that even on a bass, you'll have terrible crossover distortion.  Edit your question with scope pictures, please -- it'll help us figure out the problem.  If you have a 2-channel scope, post input vs. output while plucking the highest string -- it should settle out to nearly sinusiodal after a bit, before the note dies away completely.

Comment: Oh -- and as pictured, you're biasing RL with about 4.5V.  That'll do odd things, for sure.  You should have a DC blocking cap just to the left of RL.

Comment: Why do you have  large capacitor directly to ground on the output? That will make it oscillate.

Comment: @TimWescott: I've added the output coupling cap to the schematic, I used one when testing the circuit, so that's not it. About the crossover distortion: Shouldn't the op amp's feedback loop take care of that, as it will keep the output equal to the input? Though I guess that would also depend on the op amp's slew rate?

I'll add the oscilloscope plots when I get a chance.

Comment: @KevinWhite The cap at the output in parallel to the 70 Ohms is supposed to model the headphones' load capacitance, not an actual capacitor in my circuit

Comment: What value is it? I can't read it very well, it looks like 400nF, that will make the circuit unstable. Headphones will be better modeled with just the resistor. As Tim states you should have a DC blocking capacitor before the load as well. As others have stated there will be crossover distortion that the low slew rate of the LM358 will not take care of well. It can only do ~1v/us.

Comment: @KevinWhite if you click on the "simulate this circuit" link it'll open up larger.

Comment: The [TI data sheet for the LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) lists the slew rate as \$\frac{0.3\mathrm{V}}{\mu s}\$.  At crossover, the output needs to transition by about \$1.2\mathrm{V}\$ between the time that one transistor turns off and the other turns on.  During that time, there'll be a flat spot.  That's not much, but I suspect it'd be audible.  I also suspect that there'll be some "bounce" as the op-amp catches up to the transistors working again.

Comment: @Mathis You will have cross-over distortion for the reasons Tim mentioned. However, I'm a little worried about the wire from the output back to the (-) input of the opamp. Try putting a \$4.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor in parallel with perhaps \$470\:\text{pF}\$ and using that as your feedback instead of just a wire. I'm just curious, so humor me.

Comment: I've added biasing to the push-pull stage to eliminate crossover distortion (if there ever was any). Also, I've replaced the feedback path by an RC network, as suggested by @jonk. However, I'm still getting the same distorted output.

Comment: It's a little counter-intuitive, but higher-speed op amps are needed to effectively use capacitive feedback network to reduce high frequency noise and oscillations, particularly at low gains.  You also might try an RC network at the positive terminal.  Also important is a decoupling cap right across the opamp power terminals.